# Cannot run demo Tizen clock app on emulator

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I'm learning Tizen on Samsung wearable through Tizen's developer site. Followed the analog clock example, to the point of uploading. When I hit the Run button on IDE, last few lines of console shows

> ```
> Installed the package: Id(BIQsvZ9SAx), Version(1.0.0)
> ```
>
> [Uploading RDS information to target...]
>   Tizen application is successfully launched.
>   The application is not available for run. So the application is just installed.
>   (9.613 sec)

The clock app is nowhere to be found on the watch simulator. No other error occured. It just finsihes and not run anything.

I do have

> tizen:category name="com.samsung.wmanager.WATCH_CLOCK"

in my config.xml.

Have been searching the web for some answer, yet it seems I'm alone. Any help to get this to work is much appreciated.

N.B. I can get "Hello World" to work though. It's just the watch demo does not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My terrible mistake. The clock is uploaded but won't show up automatically. I have to select it in settings deliberately (unlike Android which pops up the newly uploaded app immediately).

My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

**Watch face** apps will have following in their config.xml  which differentiate it with other apps.

```
<tizen:category name="http://tizen.org/category/wearable_clock"/>
```

Watch face needs to be selected from list of watchface apps installed on Gear S2 device, it doesn't start automatically.

Other category apps will be auto launched on installation from tizen sdk.

A watchface app **cannot** be tested on **Gear Emulator/Simulator**. It can only be tested on Original Gear Device. But there is hack to test watchface on Gear S2 Emulator.

**Hack**

Comment the above mentioned line in **config.xml** to launch the watch face app as similar to hello world app.

Comment: I'm using 2.4.1 and one actually can test Gear S2 on the emulator. But your hack of commenting out that <category> tag does help in development efficiency. Thanks.

Comment: I was driving crazy because the simulator doesn't give you any warning that it cannot run watchfaces... thanks!